# simple python program with gmpy2 is crashing (but i can do in scala???) -> overflow in mpz type / Aborted (core dumped

Tags: python, largenumber

I am running into an issue with the above mentioned library, running a very simple example -- which I can get working using similar libraries in JVM land (using Scala).

The Scala code snippet below prints 'good', while the python version dies with the error in the title of the post.

Wondering if this is a known bug.. or am i doing something silly in the Python version of the calculation ?   thnx in advance !

**Scala**

```
import java.math.BigInteger

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.Base64


object Example extends App {
  val pstr: String ="134078079299425970995740249982058461274793658205923933" +
    "77723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031" +
    "858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084171"
  val gstr = "11717829880366207009516117596335367088558084999998952205"  +
    "59997945906392949973658374667057217647146031292859482967"  +
    "5428279466566527115212748467589894601965568"
  val hstr = "323947510405045044356526437872806578864909752095244"  +
    "952783479245297198197614329255807385693795855318053"  +
    "2878928001494706097394108577585732452307673444020333"


  val decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder.decode("Mzc1Mzc0MjE3ODMw")
  val decodedString = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)     // obfuscated ... can't fall into wrong hands

  val p: BigInteger = new BigInteger(pstr)
  val g: BigInteger = new BigInteger(gstr)
  val h: BigInteger = new BigInteger(hstr)
  val exponent: BigInteger = new BigInteger(decodedString)

  val recover = g.modPow(exponent, p)

  if (recover == h)
    print("good")
  else
    print("bad")
}
```

**Python version**

```py
import gmpy2
import base64

pstr = "134078079299425970995740249982058461274793658205923933" + \
       "77723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031" + \
       "858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084171"

gstr = "11717829880366207009516117596335367088558084999998952205" + \
       "59997945906392949973658374667057217647146031292859482967" + \
       "5428279466566527115212748467589894601965568"

hstr = "323947510405045044356526437872806578864909752095244" + \
       "952783479245297198197614329255807385693795855318053" + \
       "2878928001494706097394108577585732452307673444020333"

p = gmpy2.mpz(pstr)
g = gmpy2.mpz(gstr)
h = gmpy2.mpz(hstr)

secret_exponent_encoded = base64.b64decode(b'Mzc1Mzc0MjE3ODMw').decode('utf-8')
exponent = gmpy2.mpz(secret_exponent_encoded)
recover = (g ** exponent) % p

if (recover == h):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Comment: `recover = (g** exponent)  % p` is not a good idea because it first computes the exponentiation, generating an enormous integer, and only then does a reduction. Instead use `gmp2.powmod(g, exponent, p)`. It will be much faster and use very little memory. You don't really need `gmpy2` at all here, python's regular integers are arbitrary precision. For the modular exponentiation you can use python function `pow(g, exponent, p)`

Comment: Thanks President Polk !       One of my favorite presidents and favorite streets in SF ;^).   i accepted the answer that aligns w/ your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `gmpy2` version 2.2.0a1 I get this error instead:

```py
   recover = (g** exponent)  % p
               ^^~~~~~~~~~
ValueError: pow() outrageous exponent
```

That makes sense. There's not a computer on the planet with enough RAM to compute `g**exponent` here. The underlying library (GMP) does not handle out-of-memory gracefully - it just aborts the program.

With the following change, though, it runs fine and prints `true`:

```
    #recover = (g** exponent)  % p
    recover = gmpy2.powmod(g, exponent, p)
```

Comment: fantastic !      basically same thing  i did in scala.. But.. i'm a python dummy at this point.. thnx for straightening me out!